# Mysql -- inserting in table with only an auto incrementing column

Tags: mysql

Lets say we have table A with just one column, id(which is the primary key)

How do we insert a new row into the table without specifying an id?

I tried this

```
INSERT INTO A (`id`) VALUES (NULL)
```

and it doesn't work

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that id, the primary key has the auto_increment and NOT NULL attribute.

**Edit 2:** The exact error when running the query above is

```
Column 'id' cannot be null
```

Comment: Why not share with us how exactly it's failing to work?

Comment: PK field does not allow duplicate values nor NULL values

Comment: Primary key fields must be NOT NULL.

Comment: @arvinsim - Your description of the set-up looks correct. You've probably failed to do some of the steps you claim you've done.

Comment: @Alvaro Tried to do a simple insert in the framework and in phpmyadmin. Both of them returned the same error above. I was under the assumption that if NULL is give as the value of an auto incrementing row, it will just try to insert it using  the next auto increment value. Maybe this only works on tables with more than 1 column?

Comment: can you post your table definition pls :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As soon as 'id' as the auto-increment enable (assuming ID is an integer), you can just do:

```
INSERT INTO A (id) values (null)
```

and 'id' will keep incrementing each time.

Comment: I don't think this works. I tried it and it tried to insert the digit 0. Since I was trying to insert 5 times, it produces a duplicate entry error.

Comment: @arvinsim: There must be some problem with your setup. MySQL accepts both `NULL` and `0` as values for an auto_increment column, and interprets them as meaning "use the next ID".

Comment: This worked for me with a MySQL database.  It does in fact increment the id each time.

Comment: The problem comes to get that number, sigh!!

Answer (score 6):

only works if you're using an auto_increment primary key (PK) as every PK must have a unique, non null value.

```
drop table if exists A;
create table A
(
id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key
)
engine=innodb;

insert into A (id) values (null),(null);

mysql> select * from A order by id;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Yes it is an auto-incrementing field

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that's the set-up described in the question :-?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, then I noticed that I didn't apply the changes when I changed `id` to primary key + not null + auto incremental.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `table` () VALUES ();
```

is working too.

Answer (score -1):

Try it without the ``..
As in:

INSERT INTO A(sid) VALUES(NULL); //i used sid instead of id...

worked fine for me..

Also wwhile creating the table A, specify unique(sid)...
i.e

create table A(sid int(3) not null auto_increment unique(sid));

Comment: Quoting style should not change anything